# jquery menu using slidetoggle() slight issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

Iv created a basic vertical sliding menu which can be seen here on the left vertical grey bar:

http://www.switchcreative.co.uk/tuckagefinewines/

When you click on a country the sub-menu items slide down and the top level + sign changes to a - but how to I change it back to + when the menu is closed again. I guess I want to add an even to slidetoggles upward motion? but not sure how. I tried using an if statement to change it but couldn't get it to work here is my closest version to working the way Id like:

```
 function initMenu() {
 $('#menu ul:not(.active)').hide();
 $('#menu li a.top_a').click(
 function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next().slideToggle('normal');
    $(this).siblings('.plus').replaceWith(' - ');   
   }
 );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're removing the `span.plus` try setting the text like this:

```
if($(this).siblings('.plus').text() == '+')
    $(this).siblings('.plus').text('-');
else
    $(this).siblings('.plus').text('+');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check the CSS height of every sub-element. If it's greater than 0, your .plus-element should replaced by a "+" again. slideToggle() does nothing else than changing the height of en element. You can read about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
$(this).siblings('.plus').replaceWith(' - ');
```

to:

```
if($(this).siblings('.plus').length > 0){
    $(this).siblings('.plus').removeClass('.plus').addClass('.minus').text(' - ');
}
else {
    $(this).siblings('.minus').removeClass('.minus').addClass('.plus').text(' + ');
}
```

Or even have two spans:

```
<span class="plus"> + </span><span class="minus"> - </span>
```

`.plus` is visible and `.minus` is `display: none;`. Then when you toggle the next element just do:

```
$(this).siblings('.plus, .minus').toggle();
```